# Receive events from a listener object

Tags: java

How can I register to be notified of a listener object's events?

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve can be visualized through this:

this.mouseMoved() = listener.mouseMoved()

```
Class Secondary implements MouseMotionListener {

    public Secondary(MouseMotionListener listener) {

        // Here Secondary needs to be registered to the same observer that
        // listener is getting notified from so that the Secondary class's
        // mouseMoved() and mouseDragged() both fire at the same time and 
        // with the same MouseEvents as the listener's.
    }

    @Override
    void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        // This needs to be essentially the same as the events fired
        // in the constructor's parameter object
    }

    @Override
    void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        // This needs to be essentially the same as the events fired
        // in the constructor's parameter object
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, don't know what the meaning of `this.mouseMoved() = listener.mouseMoved()` should be. Why don't you call `Component.addMouseMotionListener()` with a second listener? Then you have two listeners receiving the same events.

Comment: @vanje this sounds like what I'm looking for. I have access to the original listener, I just need to add the second one as a listener to its master. I tried Component.addMouseMotionListener() but I can't just call that in a vaccuum apparently.

Comment: mouseMotionListener is activated when the mouse passes or is dragged over a given component. I'm assuming that both objects are in the same GUI class and not overlapping. I see no issue in this as far as I understand the situation. The response event in each case is fired whenever the mouse moves or is dragged on either one or the other component. If there are common actions these can be put into a private method that is callable by each component. Response events may be totally different, totally the same or a mix.

Comment: @Trunk Only the main listener object is part of the GUI class, the one I'm trying to pass its events to is completely separate. I'm trying to pass the events that object A fires to object B by registering B to the same observer as A is.

Comment: Best thing to do is for you to experiment yourself  with adding a mouseMotionListener to : (1)  object A in the GUI; and also to (2) an instance of the class to which object belongs. To achieve this you declare the second class' instance inside the GUI class.

Answer (score 0):

A listener is fired by someone that calls the methods, JComponents accepts mouselisteners as arguments so you must set it:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
jFrame.add(panel);
panel.addMouseListener(new Secondary());
```

You can use the delegate pattern if you want to dispatch the events.

```
class Secondary implements MouseMotionListener {
MouseMotionListener other;
public Secondary(MouseMotionListener listener) {
    other = listener;
}

@Override
void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    other.mouseMoved(e);
}

@Override
void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    other.mouseDragged(e);
}
}
```